# How to loop through all pdf files in a folder, if folder name is in a variable in bash?

Tags: bash

I have two folders original_images and pdf_backup.Those folders contain pdf files,if i am saving that location in a variable how can loop through all pdf files.

```
if some count > 10 
  location=/home/BACKUP/teamshare2/my\ Raw\ Data/"$1"/"$2"/"$3"/original_images/*.pdf
else
  location=/home/BACKUP/teamshare2/my\ Raw\ Data/"$1"/"$2"/"$3"/pdf_backup/*.pdf
for f in $location
      ---pdf files---
```

when i am doing this,`for loop` is not executing,but if i  am giving that path directly means loop is executing.why is it so? How can i solve this ? Thank You In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store wildcards in variables; just store the fixed part of the path in a variable, put the reference to it in double-quotes so it won't get confused by spaces in the path, and then put the wildcard part without quotes:

```
if some count > 10 
  location="/home/BACKUP/teamshare2/my Raw Data/$1/$2/$3/original_images"
else
  location="/home/BACKUP/teamshare2/my Raw Data/$1/$2/$3/pdf_backup"
for f in "$location"/*.pdf
```

(Note: I also switched to a simpler everything-in-double-quotes format for setting `location`, rather than mixing escapes and double-quotes.)

Answer (score 0):

> I have two folders folder_one and folder_two.Those folders contain pdf files,if i am saving that location in a variable how can loop through all pdf files.

Use an array not a simple variable.

```
array1=(folder_one/*.pdf)

array2=(folder_two/*.pdf)
```

Concat them together

```
array=(folder_one/*.pdf)
array+=(folder_two/*.pdf)
```

Comment: how i can apply this in my case?

Comment: change the `array` to `location` and add the path according to your test, `location=("/home/BACKUP/teamshare2/my Raw Data/$1/$2/$3/original_images/"*.pdf)`